# Concatenation function name in js

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Is there any way to concat a js function name?  right now I have this:

```
switch (playId) {
        case "11":
            play11();
            break;
        case "22":
            play22();
            break;
        case "33":
            play33();
            break;
        case "44":
            play44();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

and I want to do somthing like this:

```
var function = "play" + playId + "()";
```

and call it.. what is the best way if possible?

---

**Solution:**

What I did with the help of `thefourtheye` and `xdazz` is very simple:

```
var playFunction = window["play" + playId];
    playFunction();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If these functions are defined in global scope, then you could get them from the global object:

```
var foo = window["play" + taskId];
```

Otherwise you could put them together in an object like another answer suggested.

Comment: It's not limited to the global scope(but out of scope for this question) but I would always try to avoid it. It can break after minifying the code and searching for unused functions becomes impossible in larger projects. Using a 'dictionary' object is not much more work and very readable. - answer is good though.

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to put them in an object like this

```
var functions = {
    11: play11,
    22: play22,
    33: play33,
    44: play44
};
```

and then invoke it like this

```
functions[taksId]();
```

Since you don't want to fail if `taskId` is not found, you can do

```
if (functions.hasOwnProperty(taskId)) {
    functions[taksId]();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you put the functions in an array:

```
var functions = {
    'play1':function(){},
    'play2':function(){}
}
```

Call it like this:

```
functions['play'+number]();
```