# concatenating function names reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a unique situation in React/Next. Essentially, I am iterating in React to create divs. The iterating functionality works beautifully. I now am trying to create hide/show sections for each one of the created divs and I want to use the anchor tag to allow the hiding and showing of hidden divs. I followed [this][1] thread for the hiding element and [this][2] link for concatenating function names. However, I do not think the second link is applicable to concatenate function names in React as it says that showDogFunctions is not a function which is evidently not a good error. Can anyone help? Additionally, if anyone has more concise ways to achieve my functionality that would also be appreciated.

```
**Error**
Variable Names are a bit dif but you can easily associate.

[![Error][3]][3]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263601/concatenation-function-name-in-js
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUoxr.png
```

Comment: The more usual way to do this would be to make the dog divs their own component which would then contain the show, toggle, etc relevant to just that item.

Comment: Code works fine, you just need to add initial `dogCounter` state greater than 0, like 3 to match your map lookups. See running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/concatenating-function-names-reactjs-stackoverflow67143306-zed55).

Comment: Can you please copy&paste the error? The error you are describing shouldn't happen with this code.

Comment: @christian with a bit of imagination, there is probably a button to increase dogCounter, and for dogCounter > 3 this fails ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a state for *each component* then the state should actually be in that component. As `<div>`s do not have state, you need a functional component around them:

```
 function SingleDog({ counter }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return (
       <div key={counter} className="user-box">
         <span className="expand-more">
            <a onClick={() => setShow(it => !it)} >Toggle</a>
            {show && <div>Hi there</div>}
          </span>
        </div>
    );
 }

 function DogList() {
    const [dogCount, setDogCount] = useState(0);
   
   const dogs = [];

   for(let count = 0; count < dogCount; count++) {
      dogs.push( <SingleDog counter={counter} /> );
   }

   return <>
     {dogs}
     {/* ... more content here */}
   </>;
 }
```

If you need to influence the state of all components from the parent, e.g. close all expands, then you need to lift state up again. However instead of having n states, use one state with an array or object, e.g.:

```
  const [show, setShow] = useState({ });

     //...
     <SingleDog
      counter={counter}
      show={show[counter]}
      setShow={() => setShow(prev => ({ ...prev, [counter]: !prev[counter] }))}
     />
```